# Encryption web.config file "aspnet_regiis.exe" not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, web-config

I work with asp.net fromwork 4.0 web site. and I want to encrypt web.config file connectionString. I used `aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionString" "file Location"`

but it's not working. Rather I'm getting only the error message as shown below

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>  
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>

  <connectionStrings>    
    <add name="MS_EAS_LocationConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=help\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MS.EAS.LOCATION;User ID=sa;Password=123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Can this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365210/failed-to-encrypt-the-section-connectionstrings-using-provider-rsaprotectedco

Comment: No this link can't help me.

Comment: how did you specify the provider? can you show us your web.config?

Comment: @user1859022 web.config file content added.

Comment: @BuddhikaSamith hum - tried to encrypt your config, worked on my machine...
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" C:\tmp`

Comment: yes its work thank you.