# Encryption of connection strings in Web.config c#

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, webapi

I have a Web API in .NET Framework in which right now UID and Password are present as plain text in connection strings. Instead of the plain text, I want these values as encrypted in Web config because of the security scans.

Connection strings in the plain text:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataConnection1" connectionString="Data Source=server1;Initial Catalog=db1;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DataConnection2" connectionString="Data Source=server1;Initial Catalog=db2;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DataConnection3" connectionString="Data Source=server2;Initial Catalog=db123;UID=usn;PWD=password@123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I did a research regarding the encryption of the connection strings. And one of the ways is to use ASPNET_REGIIS utility. But due to some access related constraints on the server where application is deployed I cant use RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider.

Just wanted help to find out some other ways to encrypt the connection strings of web config.

Comment: The way we solved this issue was to use integrated authentication, then you don't have to put the username/password in the web.config at all.  You just create an active directory ID that has rights to your DBs, then have the IIS App Pool for your application run under that ID.  Another way to solve it would be to keep the connection strings in the registry.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use the RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider. There are some alternatives, mainly the DpapiProtectedConfigurationProvider ([Specify a Protected Configuration Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/68ze1hb2%28v%3Dvs.100%29)).

It is also possible to protect the config programmatically ([ProtectSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.configuration.sectioninformation.protectsection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)):

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
ConfigurationSection connectionStrings = config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
```

If you are experiencing problems using the *.ProtectedConfigurationProvider with Administrator privileges, have a look here: [Web.config encryption as normal user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365210/failed-to-encrypt-the-section-connectionstrings-using-provider-rsaprotectedco/45347729#45347729)